# Как реализовать каррирование в PHP

Tags: php

Пусть у меня есть анонимная функция

```
$add = function($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
};
```

Как можно реализовать функцию `curry`, такую, что:

```
$add5 = curry($add, [5]);
echo $add5(3); // Выведет 8
echo $add5(5); // Выведет 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей можно использовать функции [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php), [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php) и немного магии [замыканий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Например так:

```
function curry(callable $func, array $args) {
    // Создаем новую анонимную функцию, связывая исходную функцию и
    // массив "зафиксированных" аргументов через замыкание.
    return function () use ($func, $args) {
        // Вызываем исходную функцию и возвращаем ее результат.
        return call_user_func_array(
            $func,
            // Объединяем "зафиксированные" аргументы с теми, что
            // будут переданы в каррированную функцию.
            array_merge($args, func_get_args())
        );
    };
};

$add = function($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
};

$add5 = curry($add, [5]);
echo $add5(3); // 8
echo $add5(5); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Оригинал: [Еще раз о каррировании и частичном применении в PHP](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144160/)

Код:

```
<?php
function curry($callback, $args = array()){
/* $callback - исходная функция
   $args     - массив ее аргументов, если они уже определены */

    /* строим каррированную функцию */
    $ret = function() use($callback, $args){

        /* определяем число аргументов исходной функции */
        $func = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
        $num = $func->getNumberOfParameters();

        /* добавляем новые аргументы к уже имеющемуся набору */ 
        $args = array_merge($args, func_get_args());

        /* если уже набралось необходимое число аргументов, */
        if(count($args) >= $num){
            /* то подставляем их в исходную функцию 
               и возвращаем результат вычисления */
            return call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
        }
        /* если же аргументов меньше, чем необходимо, */
        else {
            /* то рекурсивно вызываем каррирование исходной функции
               с более полным набором аргументов */
            return curry($callback, $args);
        }
    };

    return $ret;
}

function add($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }

$add = curry("add");

$inc = $add(1);
$dec = $add(-1);
var_dump($inc(6)); // выведет 7
var_dump($dec(8)); // выведет 7

// PHP7
var_dump($add(1)(2)); // выдает 3
```

Тест: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec8117e986022b355a19ff0f259623b0d2859df1

Comment: Круто. Хотя явное определение числа параметров, на мой взгляд, плохое решение.

Comment: Ну и использование `ReflectionFunction` делает решение неприменимым к `callable` вида `[$object, 'method']`